# Is there any way to import color themes from Aptana Studio 3 to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Aptana Studio 3 has a way to import, export your color settings.

Does Eclipse have something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File -> Import -> General -> Preferences

Comment: I mean in Aptana there is a lot of cool coloring themes, is there any way to import them to the Eclipse Helios?

Comment: Choose your own and export it from Aptana, exchange Import for Export in the above, then import it in Helios. I do it like that between Eclipses.

Comment: @Roman: Don't forget to upvote and accept answers, or you will get fewer later on. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There exists a plugin for Eclipse called [Eclipse Color Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin). It allows the same kind of theming as Aptana, with even more themes available on the same site as the plugin.